# Freestyle of and through Transparent Material (with a caveat)

Tags: transparency, freestyle

I'm trying to get blender to render freestyle contours on objects behind a transparent material (literally transparent, not glass) and I can adjust the QI Range to max at 1, and while this does draw the freestyle lines on the occluded objects, it also draws freestyle lines on parts of the opaque mesh that really should be hidden. My major problem is I still want freestyle lines around the transparent object, and I want freestyle lines around objects occluded by this, but I don't want freestyle lines on objects occluded by opaque objects. Is this even possible considering freestyle doesn't know anything about materials? Is there something I can do to the backfaces of the transparent object to make freestyle appear through it but not through the other (opaque) objects?

Comment: Have you considered compositing from multiple render layers?  Have you considered using displaced, inverted-normal copies as outlines instead?  Recent geometry nodes (finally a non-destructive "join", yay) simplifies this significantly.

Comment: is it possible to mask out only a specific area in compositing to have different freestyle settings combined into one render? i did consider using inverted normals for outlines instead, but i abandoned the idea as more complicated than what i'm really after. i may have to go back to that.

Comment: absolutely, although it might require multiple freestyle layers, and I wouldn't be the one to ask about it anyways-- just might provide some focus for an alternate question

Comment: that was the trick (alpha over freestyle from another scene with just the transparent object)! thank you!